# The fastest way to pass java bitmap pixels to jni

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to find the best/fastest way to pass a bitmap from java to JNI. Next is how I do this operation at the moment. Can this be improved, or is there any other faster way?

```
void JNIBitmap::setBuffer(JNIEnv* env, const jobject bitmap)
{
    // Allocate native pixels buffer

    AndroidBitmapInfo bitmapInfo;
    AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &bitmapInfo)

    this->bufferWidth  = bitmapInfo.width;
    this->bufferHeight = bitmapInfo.height;
    this->bufferSize   = this->bufferWidth * this->bufferHeight * 4;
    this->buffer       = new uint8_t[this->bufferSize];

    // Copy pixels to native buffer

    void* bitmapPixels;
    AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &bitmapPixels)

    memcpy((void*)this->buffer, bitmapPixels, this->bufferSize);

    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
}
```

Comment: The faster way would be to not copy the pixels. As I understand it, you're locking the pixel buffer *address*, not the Bitmap, which means the Bitmap can continue to be used, and is guaranteed not to be moved around in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just call AndroidBitmap_lockPixels.
So in the constructor of JNIBitmap you would do this:

```
void* bitmapPixels;
AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &bitmapPixels)
```

Then in the destructor you would do this:

```
AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels( env, bitmap);
```