# How to access drawable file from NDK in Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-drawable

In my Android project, I want to access a drawable file using c/c++ from the android-ndk, like R.drawable.some_drawable.xml.

How can I achieve such functionality ?

Comment: you cannot, what would you like to do that for?

Comment: I have a file which I don't like putting in assets or raw folder. Any suggestions ?

Comment: so read it from c/c++ using the full path, but you will have access to raw data, not to any `Drawable` object

Comment: just wanted to make sure if any api is available already. The raw data is just fine.

Comment: here you have all the apis: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html

Comment: Easiest way would be to pass it to JNI as a bitmap. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603218/the-fastest-way-to-pass-java-bitmap-pixels-to-jni/32619036#32619036

Comment: @WLGfx `R.drawable.some_drawable.xml` as a `Bitmap`?

Comment: Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap

Comment: @WLGfx he wants to access xml file (or `Drawable` object), not a `Bitmap`

Comment: Ah yes, i went to quickly on that. An xml drawable can be converted to a bitmap. Hopefully this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35574775/2979092

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150601/discussion-between-wlgfx-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, using JNI you are limited to some primitive data types:

> The mapping between Java data types and data types used in native code is pretty straightforward. The naming scheme remains the same: the native data type name is preceded by the character 'j', followed by all lowercase data type name equivalent to Java. JNI also includes another data type named jsize, which stores the length or an array or string.

```
void -> void : None
byte -> jbyte : 8-bit signed. Range is -27 to 27 - 1
int -> jint : 32-bit signed. Range is -231 to 231 - 1
float -> jfloat : 32 bits. Represent a real number as small as 1.4 x 10-45 and as big as 3.4 x 1038 (approx.), positive or negative
double -> jdouble : 64 bits. Represent a real number as small as 4.9 x 10-324 and as big as 1.7 x 10308 (approx.), positive or negative
char -> jchar : 16-bit unsigned. Range is 0 to 65535
long -> jlong : 64-bit signed. Range -263 to 263 - 1
short -> jshort : 16-bit signed. Range is -215 to 215 - 1
boolean -> jboolean : Unsigned 8 bits. true and false
```

Your solution would be saving your Drawable in cache folder and pass file address to your NDK code and read it in C/C++.

[How can I write a Drawable resource to a File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174399/how-can-i-write-a-drawable-resource-to-a-file)